# Prove that R and R* are numerically equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ are numerically equivalent (with $\mathbb{R}^*$ being the set without $0$).

I made the exercise, and added the solution within. The bold text is the part i didn't understand.

We define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x$. Because $f$ is one-to-one it follows that $\vert \mathbb{R}^* \vert\leq \vert \mathbb{R}\vert$. By Corollary 15 (of my book) the sets $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are numerically equivalent and so there exists a bijective function $g:\mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$.
**This function can be used to define a one-to-one function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^*$ where $h(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.** Thus $\vert \mathbb{R}^* \vert\leq \vert \mathbb{R}\vert$ and by "Schroder Bernstein theorem" follows $\vert \mathbb{R}^* \vert= \vert \mathbb{R}\vert$.

It's obvious i'm missing something here. In what manner do we use the function $g$ to "give" us this function $h$. Thanks!

Comment: The language may be a little clumsy but the concept is clear.  $h=g$ is a bijection, and therefore a $1-1$ function, with range $(0, 1) \subseteq \Bbb R^*$.

Comment: I think i get it. So what it basically says is that we now define a one-to-one function $h$ where for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the values of the range of $h$ are equal to the range of $g$ , so within $(0,1)$. Thank you!

Comment: If $f:A\to B$ is a bijection.  And $B\subsetneq C$ and $h:A\to C\supset B =f(A)$ via $h(x) = f(x)$ then $h$ is one to one but is not onto. So we have $g:\mathbb R\to (0,1)$ and $(0,1)\subsetneq \mathbb R^*$ ad $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^*\supset (0,1) = g(\mathbb R)$ is onto to one but not onto ($h(x): h(x)\ge 1$ or $f(x) \le 0$ never occurs.)

Comment: By numerically equivalent, do you mean of the same cardinality? If so, other adjectives you could use are equinumerous or equipollent. (I prefer that last one because of the related term, infrapollent, for when one set can be injected into the other.)

Comment: @J.G. yes i meant same cardinality. They use "numerically equivalent" in my book. I already noticed that the word was less popular/used. Thanks!

Comment: @Wouter Fair enough. I'll add that phrase to my list of synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof using the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem is correct.

A simpler proof is as follows: The map $f\!:\>{\mathbb R}^*\to{\mathbb R}$ defined by $f(x):=x-1$ when $x\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$, and $f(x):=x$ otherwise, is bijective.

Comment: That is indeed more simple and easy to understand. Thank you!!